# Implement a cross-fade animation in CSS between image slides

Tags: html, css, animation, slider, slideshow

I have made a slideshow using the tutorial outlines [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow)

Ideally I would like the transistions bewteen the slides to crossfade when clicked, rather than flash to white and fade in. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

So far I have tried this.

HTML

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
        <div id="sliderWrapper">
            <div id="slider" ondragstart="return false;">
                <img class="mySlides fade" src="../images/lupe1.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides fade" src="../images/lupe2.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides fade" src="../images/lupe3.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides fade" src="../images/lupe4.jpg">

                <div class="overlay-controls left-control" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"></div>                
                <div class="overlay-controls right-control" onclick="plusDivs(1)"></div>

            </div>                                              
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.contentWrapper {
    margin-left: 235px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}

#sliderWrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0
}

#slider {
    width: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    display:block
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 60px;
}   

img.mySlides{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
}


.fade {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

JS

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");  
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }  

    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: You need to **provide some code**, not just a link to an external website. **What have you tried so far to implement what you want?** ... On a side note, *w3schools* is usually outdated and not a good reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question with the code I have tried so far. Do you have any other resources that you can recommend instead of w3schools?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible implementations for a crossfade, however a simple way to achieve this is using transitions instead of changing the display of the element. (This causes the automatic hide of the entire element) For this you can set a the transition property of each slide to this:

```
img.mySlides{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

And then toggle the opacity instead the display property in your javascript like:

```
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");  
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }  

    x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
}
```

*Note that for this to work you will need to position absolutely all the slides within the slider container so they are taken out of the flow and positioned in the same place.

Hope it helps!